# How to get the cookies saved in a file by using python?

Tags: python

I have two methods

```
  def save_cookie(): 
      cookie = cookielib.MozillaCookieJar('cookie.txt') 
      opener = urllib2.build_opener(HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie)) 
      req = urllib2.Request(url=targeturl,headers=targetheaders) 
      opener.open(req) 
      cookie.save(ignore_discard=True,ignore_expires=True) 

  def get_cookie(): 
      cookie = cookielib.MozillaCookieJar() 
      print cookie.load(filename='cookie.txt').name
```

the first method is saving the cookies in a file from response.
I want to use the second method to get the cookies from the file,
but the type of **cookie.load(filename='cookie.txt')** is None
so...

Answer (score 0):

After you call `cookie.load()`, iterate over the `cookie` object to obtain each cookie in turn:

```
for acookie in cookie:
    print acookie.name, acookie.value
```

Response to comment #1:

> the type of cookie is None!so it prints nothing.It seems like that the
>   file wasn't loaded success.

`cookie.load()` does not return any value.  It either succeeds, or it throws an exception.  So you can't use it in the way your original program tries to use it, like this:

```
    print cookie.load(filename='cookie.txt').name
```

Change that line to this:

```
    cookie.load(filename='cookie.txt')
```

and then do:

```
    for acookie in cookie:
        print acookie
```

If that still doesn't show any cookies, then look at the content of your **cookie.txt** file.  If it doesn't contain any cookie data then the problem is in the part of the program that tries to collect the cookies, not in the part that tries to show them.  (Are you certain that the response from this URL contains cookies?)

If the **cookie.txt** file does contain cookies then please update your question to show that file's contents and the latest source for your `get_cookie()` function.

Comment: the type of cookie is None!so it prints nothing.It seems like that the file wasn't loaded success.

Answer (score 0):

print cookie.load(filename='cookie.txt')

the value of function--load() is none.
I think you should do as follows:

cookie.load('cookie.txt')

print cookie.name